# Content Editor Web Part making page uneditable

Tags: sharepoint-online, cewp

I am new to Sharepoint Online and was trying to insert data to sharepoint list from  sharepoint page containing cotent editor web part but I guess there is some problemwith my code or something which is making web part uneditable after that.

Below is my code:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="login_javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <clocform>
        Name:<input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
        Email:<input type="email" name="email" id="email"><br>
        Password:<input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br>
        <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="loginSubmit()">
    </clocform>

</body>
```

Javascript:

```
    function loginSubmit(){
alert("Form submitted");
var context=SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var listTitle="LoginForm1";
var login_form_list=context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var ListItemCreationInformation=new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
var listItem=login_form_list.addItem(ListItemCreationInformation);

var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
var email=document.getElementById("email").value;
var password=document.getElementById("password").value;
listItem.set_item('Person',name);
listItem.set_item('Email',email);
listItem.set_item('Password',password);
listItem.update();  
context.load(listItem);  
context.executeQueryAsync(AddListItemSucceeded, AddListItemFailed);  
}  

function AddListItemSucceeded()  
{  
    alert("added");
    //retriveListItem();  
}  

function AddListItemFailed(sender, args)  
{  
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Content Editor webpart is rendered in the `BODY` of a SharePoint page, therefore your code should not have `HTML`, `Body`, or `HEAD` elements.
In addition, `clocform` is not a supported element.

You will likely need to delete this webpart from the page and recreate it.  If the webpart delete controls are also broken, you can append a `?contents=1` to the end of the url, this will bring up a list of webparts that are on the page, rather than rendering them, from there you can delete the webpart, then return to the rendered page to Edit.